# function parameter taken from a list

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, parameter-passing

So i have a function which takes multiple values:

```
def kgV(a,b, *rest):
#the function itself doesnt matter for the question
#beside that it returns an int no matter how many arguments where passed
```

now i have a list or range():

```
# for example
myRange = range(2, 10)
myList = [2,9,15]
```

Now i  want it to possible to give my Function the list or range as parameter so that it works as if i had given the every int of the range or list as parameter.

```
#how can i make this work?

kgV(myRange)
kgV(myList)
```

i tried some things like: for i in a etc
but they all returned errors :-/

edit: i just solved it using a help function but it seems a very un pythonic way of doing it, so is there a more pythonic / generic way of doing it?

```
def kgVList(liste):
    result = liste[0]
    for i in liste:
        result = kgV(i, result)
    return result
```

Comment: Be more precise. If a and b are params, both function calls won't work because one param is missing. When you keep these two params, do you want to call your fuction for each value for all combinations of a and b or what? If a[0] and a[1] should reflect the params a,b, this code doesn't make any sense at all (but can be tackled by Matthias answer).

Comment: Not sure how its not clear that a[0] and a[1] should refer to a, b?
How doesnt it make then sense? It's a thing that comes up douzens of times. Even further i'd like to know the opposite: how in gods name would it make sense if it would be anything else than that?
I ask sersioulsy, since it seems like I'm missing something.

Comment: Because the approach itself doesn't make sense at all, independent on the function kgV. Named parameters which are filled with different-sized lists, so that some named params will get filled while popping from lists? Thats hmm :-) And a pythonic way of doing the stuff in kgVList would be with the usage of reduce, despite the fact that a lot of people despise this function.

Comment: i still dont get it. All i want is that example: kgV ( [2,3,4,5] ) has the same result as  kgV ( 2,3,4,5). The *rest in the kgV function can handle any additonal passed arguments. oh i read about reduce its sounds interesting, buts it's not implemented in python 3.X

Comment: Exactly this: i don't understand why you want to pass *many* parameters instead of a list. I don't get it with this example and this is very unusual in my opinion. (Some parts in the list will be part of *rest*; and it should fail if a list of cardinality 1; and i suppose there is an internal limit on the number of arguments but i'm not sure about that). The feature of variadic arguments, which you are using intensively is not that often used in classical programming languages and i bet there is a reason for that. (yeah, there are new C++ versions supporting that stuff)

Comment: maybe a little late for a replay, anyway:

Comment: kvg is an operation on numbers like lets's say the common function sum(). So sometimes i want to know just what a+b is then i wouldnt want to write sum([a,b]) but just sum(a,b)... or the sum of 3 numbers. But sometimes i want know the sum of 10 numbers, THEN it makes sense to use a list as input. Therefore I want my function to handle both lists or multiple parameters. And as with sum, my function doesnt make any sense too, if input is just 1 number it does and should fail then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply unpack the values like this:

```
kgV(*a)
```

Comment: Yes. Yippie yay. Thats exactly what i was looking for! Very happy. :-D
Though i have worked through multiple python tutorials but none metioned this. Is there a more indepth tutorial which covers these cool things or how do find these things out by myself?

Comment: I don't actually remember how I found it, but it's called argument (un)packing. You should find plenty to read if you search for that.